# How do I create DocumentTermMatrix directly from list/vector of terms?

Tags: r, tm, lda

How do I create [DocumentTermMatrix](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tm/) directly from list/vector of terms ?

I'd like to calculate LDA for my corpus using bigrams instead of words. Thus I do following:

1. Convert each document to words via `txt.to.words`
2. Create bigrams using `stylo` package via `make.ngrams(res, ngram.size = 2)`
3. Remove bigrams where at least one word is from my stoplist

But here is the problem. [LDA](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/topicmodels/) wants `DocumentTermMatrix` as parameter. How do I create one with my bigrams instead of raw text ?

There is [example](http://tm.r-forge.r-project.org/faq.html) in tm's FAQ that explains how to `use bigrams instead of single tokens in a term-document matrix` but it produces `TermDocumentMatrix` that `LDA` won't accept.